# Fedora 15 how to switch GNOME to KDE at login time

Tags: fedora, gnome, kde

I would like to enable user ability to set Desktop to GNOME or KDE at login time.

Answer (score 3):

With GNOME and KDE installed on a Fedora 15 system, there should be a drop-down menu in your login window where you can select which display manager to use for the session.

If you want to set the default display manager, have a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671372/how-do-i-set-the-default-fedora-desktop-environment-to-gnome-instead-of-kde/4690916#4690916).

In any case, your question's not really that precise, so what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are clearly off-topic. Not only are they going to be closed, but answering them encourages others to post without considering whether the question belongs here or on another site. If you're not sure what is on-topic here, please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to familiarize yourself. Thanks.

Comment: @KindOfAutomatic: I want to be able to choose KDE or GNOME at login. Your answer is good, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to Change from KDE to Gnome, you have reboot. When the login screen comes you select the user from the list there in the bottom of the login screen you should see one drop down menu with the options KDE, GNOME.., you just select Gnome and enter the password, then you will login into Gnome session.